# Socket programming connect() function error -- "cannot convert 'main(int, char**)::sockaddr* to 'const sockaddr"

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, casting, raspberry-pi

I have been attempting for some time now to rewrite as socket programming function from Winsock to its equivalent Unix version. I am hopelessly stuck on an error with the connect() function when attempting to compile the code: *"cannot convert 'main(int, char**)::sockaddr* to 'const sockaddr"* I think it's a casting error but I am at total loss to fix it. I have recreated some of the structs Winsock uses in order to emulate the existing code. I am truly desperate as the purpose is to communicate with a device for my senior design project. Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct SOCKADDR_IN {
        short sin_family;
        u_short sin_port;
        struct in_addr sin_addr;
        unsigned char sin_zero[8];  
    }addrSrv;
    
    struct in_addr {
        union {
            struct { u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4; } S_un_b;
            struct { u_short s_w1, s_w2; } S_un_w; 
            unsigned long S_addr;
        }S_un;
    };

    struct sockaddr {
        u_short sa_family;
        char sa_data[14];
    };
    //typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;
    
    int sockClient;
    sockClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
       
    inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_IP, (char*)&addrSrv.sin_addr.s_addr);
    addrSrv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addrSrv.sin_port = htons(IP_PORT);
            
    
    connect(sockClient, (struct sockaddr *) &addrSrv, sizeof(addrSrv));
}
```

Comment: I would start removing the redefinition of all SOCKADDR_IN, in_addr and sockaddr adding the proper include statements. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-sockaddr_in or https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I looked in the header file socket.h and there is no struct definition for SOCKADDR_IN. I thought it might have been an error win the header file but I see from the linux man page that it is not a part of the header file. I started defining the structs to resolve an error with inet_pton and addrsrv, which the compiler is not seeing. But perhaps it's due to the names I have transferred from the original winsock usage, which are not defined in the inet.h header.

Comment: HI Brian, usually win and Linux struct for socket handling are very close, most of the time they have only different names. I use some #define, I can recall SOCKET_STORAGE (for ipv4 and ipv6 address on Win), on Linux I use #define SOCKET_STORAGE sockaddr_storage, making the win code running just fine on Linux too. Hope it may help, Ste

Answer (score 3):

The `struct sockaddr *` in

```
connect(sockClient, (struct sockaddr *) &addrSrv, sizeof(addrSrv));
```

refers to the struct you defined in `main()`

```
  struct sockaddr {
        u_short sa_family;
        char sa_data[14];
  };
```

However, what `connect()` expects to receive is a `const sockaddr *`, where the `sockaddr` is defined in `<sys/socket.h>`

```
/* Structure describing a generic socket address.  */
struct sockaddr
{
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sa_);    /* Common data: address family and length.  */
    char sa_data[14];       /* Address data.  */
};
```

The compiler cannot implicitly convert from `struct sockaddr *` defined by you, to a `const sockaddr *` defined by `<sys/socket.h>`.

You can remove all the struct definitions you defined in `main()`, they should have already been defined in various Unix library headers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought it was odd that I needed to write out the struct definitions, but without defining them, I get "variables ( like addrsrv) not declared in scope" errors. I negated to state my header files in the code I posted for the sake of brevity, but they are as follows...

Comment: in the code above. I'm not sure if <socket.h> is equivalent to <sys/socket.h>. Maybe I compiled the sock lib incorrectly,  but if I search: find /usr/include -name socket.h >> /usr/include -name socket.h
/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/socket.h
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/socket.h
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/asm/socket.h
/usr/include/linux/socket.h

Comment: It is <sys/socket.h>. For you, it should be the /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/socket.h, you can read through this file, you should find definition of sockaddr. You shall check why you compiler didn't find this file (or why it found another socket.h instead of this one).

Comment: What I wrote was socket.h, but someone else changed it to <socket.h>, it should really be <sys/socket.h>, I will modify the answer accordingly.